# Age validation while using line edit in qt

Tags: c++, qt

Hi guys I have come up with another problem here is my sample code :

```
QValidator *m_validator = new QIntValidator(18, 75, this);
QLineEdit *m_edit = new QLineEdit(this);
m_edit->setValidator(m_validator);
```

The problem here is that I don't want to go for **`SpinBox`**, I want to validate this `lineEdit` only but here the range doesn't work in range means if I give 1 also it allows me I know `lineEdit` works on keyboard input by single character. but I need to get whole number from `lineEdit` and validate it i tried `SIGNAL` as:

```
void    editingFinished ()
```

But still problem persist it is not validating my age.

Comment: Because `1` can be continued to be `18`? One alternative method is to subclass `QValidator` and do your checking in the virtual methods.

Comment: yeah i knw that but have to over come this so creating our own QValidator also doesn't solve  my line edit still doesn't validate.

Comment: How is it not `validating` your age? I don't quite get it...  Please explain what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to subclass `QValidator` like so:

qagevalidator.h

```
class QAgeValidator : public QValidator
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QAgeValidator )

    quint16 low, high;

public:
    explicit QAgeValidator(quint16 low, quint16 high, QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual ~QAgeValidator();

    virtual QValidator::State validate(QString &, int &) const;
    virtual void fixup(QString &) const;
};
```

And reimplement the virtual functions like so:

```
QValidator::State QAgeValidator::validate(QString &input, int &) const
{
    if (input.isEmpty())
        return Acceptable;

    quint16 i = input.toInt();
    if (!isdigit(i) || (i < low || i > high))
        return Invalid;

    return Acceptable;
}
```

This is where you're supposed to do the age validation:

```
void QAgeValidator::fixup(QString &input) const
{
    QString final;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        QChar c = input.at(i);
        if (c.isDigit())
             final += c;
    }

    input = final;
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but the problem is if i enter 11 first time it shows not acceptable but if i give again a low value it accepts value i checked using hasAcceptableInput() it is true.

Comment: tanks all but i got the validation using editingfinished() signal then ill check manually with the value